# SetDims in NTL is not working

Tags: ntl

I'm trying to use matrix functions in NTL, mat_ZZ_p . But when I try to set the dimension using SetDims() fucntion, it hangs. It is working for smaller numbers like 5 , 10 etc, But it fails even for 10000.
It hangs the whole system.
Here is the code snippet :

```
int main()
{
    ZZ p;
    long int index;
    cin >> p;
    ZZ_p::init(p);
    mat_ZZ_p A; 
    long dime = 9999;
    A.SetDims(dime,dime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code with NTL 10.3.0 an GCC 5.4 with OMP and GMP and it works fine. I used `p = 101`. What value did you use for `p`?

Comment: I'm using NTL 9-9-1. I tried for 101 now, it still won't work. Let me upgrade NTL and check .Thanks for your input

Comment: I tried with the upgraded version , it still won't work.

Comment: Did you use `-O3`?